# Multi-Threading Function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 to send a request to my API.

I read a file and for each line I use the function

```
lista = open('mylist.txt', 'r').readlines()
lista = [dab.replace('\n', '') for dab in lista]

for dab in lista:
    sdab = dab.split(':')
    login = sdab[0]
    senha = sdab[1]
    myfunction(login,senha)
```

myfunction just does a request to my api.

is it possible, for example, after taking the number of rows from the file to make threads and send the contents of each line to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite straightforward with the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package.

You'll need a function that can be called directly on each `dab` in `lista`, something like:

```
def dabify(dab):
    sdab = dab.split(':')
    login = sdab[0]
    senha = sdab[1]
    myfunction(login,senha)
```

Then, you can use a multiprocessing pool to call `dabify` on each element of `lista`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4) # specify number of processes
for result in pool.imap_unordered(dabify, lista):
    # do something with the result here if you want
    pass
```

Note that the order that the API gets called is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: Hi, I've think I badly formed my question.
What I want to do is:

I have a function that does a publishing request for my api, eg:

postdata = {'login': login, 'password': password}

requests.post ('myapi', data = postdata)

and then I print the result.

The problem is that I need to do this more than a hundred times, and it takes a lot for me to test one by one
(I use the open ('file') because of this)

What I need is for it to send more than one request at a time and I have no clue how to do this, and thanks for the response.

Comment: Yeah, that should be exactly what the above does, if I'm understanding you correctly. Assuming that `myfunction` does the publishing request for your api, the code above will send up to 4 requests at a time (or more if you change the `processes=4`)

Comment: hi! the problem is that i need to send each line from the file (don't need to be in order) and each line is different, the txt file is (for example):
fulano:detal
cicrano:deltora23

I need to send each line faster, like 5 lines at a time, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how that is different from what the code above does? `dabify` will run on each line, in several parallel processes, and you can modify it to do whatever you want with each line.